# What is _CDSnapshot_EntityName?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nstimer

I assume it has something to do with Core Data but Google and SO search are not helping me out.

I'm using NSTimer to present a modal view after a certain time and I'm invalidating the timer whenever the user interacts with the view in which case I reset the timer or the view is dismissed.

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
-[_CDSnapshot_Employee_ invalidate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

So it appears that one of my invalidate messages is sent to this CDSnapshot. It's difficult to catch since many of my views have this timer running on them.

Anyone have any idea what CDSnapshot is and why invalidate is sent to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your timer was deallocated and another object in now using its memory address.

When a timer is scheduled, it is retained by the run loop. Once the timer is removed from the run loop (either because it fired or because it was invalidated), the run loop releases it and it may be deallocated, unless you retained it. If you don't set the variable to nil when the timer becomes invalid and then try to use it again, that issue will occur.

Comment: Thanks, I set my timer to nil after I posted and I haven't seen the problem pop up again. This sounds like a logical explanation.

Comment: Nicolas, I am having the same problem but it's calling for some UITableView methods: `[_CDSnapshot_Entity tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath];`. What could be the reason? I mean, if my UITableView was deallocated, how can be that it received the didSelect method?